# Find all rows between two hours of the day

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my problem :

I have a table like this :

```
id  date                name
543 2012-07-30 09:49:08 test
544 2012-07-30 10:54:12 test2
545 2012-08-01 10:54:12 test3
```

The thing is, I want to select all the records that were registred `today` between (for exemple) 9 and 12. How can I achieve this ?

I know how to do it like "HOURS(date) between 9 and 12" but I want MySQL to take in consideration the date of the day.

Thanks !

Comment: What did you try? given you know todays date..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update - this should be even better provided that you have the date column indexed:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
  date>=str_to_date(concat("2012-02-03"," 09"),"%Y-%m-%d %h") 
 AND 
  date<=str_to_date(concat("2012-02-03"," 12"),"%Y-%m-%d %h")
```

old version:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date)=DATE(NOW()) AND HOUR(date)>=9 AND HOUR(date)<=12
```

this is not very optimal. ideally add separate [indexed] column that will contain the date-part of your timestamps.

alternatively build in your code the query using current date concatenated with lower/upper hour boundaries.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try your request I get the following error :
`FUNCTION prc6.HOURS does not exist`
(prc6 is my database)

Comment: I think he meant `HOUR()` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Comment: Working great ! I'll consider your hints !
Thanks. :)

Comment: @bendataclear - you're right. it's fixed; thanks for noticing.

Comment: I have to mention that it is not advisable to use functions around selected columns `WHERE DATE(date)...` due to performance issues.

Comment: @njk - indeed; that's why i suggest using separate column or use application logic to build the query to avoid full table scans.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sql 2008 you can do the following:

```
select 
ID
,cast([Date] as Date) as dt
,cast([Date] as Time) as tm
,name
from table
where cast([Date] as Time) BETWEEN '09:00:00' AND '12:00:00'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I do not have SQL 2008. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the date column is index, this will give you better performance

```
where   date_col>=date_add(current_date,interval 9 hour)
    date_col<=date_add(current_date,interval 12 hour)
```